# Period of the function $\sin (8\pi \{x\})$

Tags: algebra-precalculus, periodic-functions

My question is to to find the period of 
$$\sin(8\pi\{x\}),$$ 
where $\{\cdot\}$-is the fractional part of function.

I know that the period of $\{\cdot\}$ is 1 and the period of $\sin(8\pi x)$ is $1/4$. But how to find the overall period of the given function?

Comment: What happens on the boundary of $[0,1]$? Study two points such as $1-a$ and $(1-a)+1/4$?

Comment: Hint: $x - \{x\}$ is always an integer. For any integer $k$,  $\sin( ... + 8\pi k ) = ?$

Comment: But, the given function is a composition of two functions. So, how to find the period of a composite function if I know the periods of the individual functions?

Comment: For the general case, if $T_{g}$ is "the" period of $g$, then $T_{g}$ will be "a" period but not necessary "the" period for $f\circ g$. Assuming $f\circ g$ is not a constant function, "the" period of $f\circ g$ will be $T_{g}$ divided by some integer $m$. There are no standard method to figure out what $m$ should be. One common trick is to pick some random numbers from $a \in f(g(\mathbb{R}))$ and look at the size of the preimage in $[0,T_g)$, i.e. the set $(f\circ g)^{-1}(a) \cap [0,T_{g})$. If you can find an $a$ to make this set a singleton, then you known $m = 1$ and $T_{fg} = T_{g}$.

Answer (score 2):

$\sin(8 \pi \{x\})
 = \sin(8 \pi ( x - \lfloor x \rfloor))
 = \sin(8 \pi x - 8 \pi \lfloor x \rfloor)
 = \sin(8 \pi x)$,

hence $\sin(8 \pi \{x\})$ has period $\frac{1}{4}$.

Answer (score 0):

Let $g(f(x))$ be the composition of $g$ and $f$.

Further, suppose that $g(x)$ is an odd function, so that $g(f(x)) = -g(f(-x))$ .

Then it follows , that the period of $g(f(x))$ must be same as period of $f(x)$ because :

$g(f(x+T)) = g(f(x))$

In your example, let $g(x) =$ sin$(8πx)$ and $f(x) =$ {$x$}

As established above, period of $g(f(x))$ is same as that of $f(x)$ . Hence, period of sin$(8π${$x$}) is same as that of {$x$} , which is 1 .